# Why is my two year old A/C compressor cycling every 10 seconds?

Tags: air-conditioning

My central A/C compressor is coming on and off every 10 seconds or so.   It's only about two years old.

I'm familiar with short-cycling, but that's usually in cycles of 1 to 5 minutes.  I've experienced that with my previous system that had a slow leak.  But I have never experienced or heard of short cycling so frequent, every 10 seconds.

What are possible causes and are there any DIY diagnostics I can do while I wait for the installer to come out?

The fan is running fine while this happens.

**Edit**

As noted in comments the compressor has diagnostic lights.  I should have known that.   Sadly this is the diagnosis: "Yellow Alert 4".  Which I believe is not a DIY job and *hopefully* a warranty job.  :(

It's not fault 2 - low voltage or bad connections.  The contactor is clean and functional and the cooling fan is starting and spinning nicely.  So it must be condition 4.1, 4.3 or 4.4

[image]

Comment: Did you install a new thermostat? Did you wire it correctly? If you set the temperature 5 degrees lower than ambient then does it short cycle still? Does it do this even when the desired temp is 5 degree above ambient? If you have a newer furnace which displays status codes on the control board then you should check those out. My new furnace will show either AC1/AC2 followed by A01-A10 to let me know the furnace is requesting 1st/2nd stage cooling along with the fan speed percentage; A01 being 10%.

Comment: This sounds more like a loose connection where the motor is trying to start.

Comment: Check the compressor contactor.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus it's not a thermostat problem, but your reminding me that my (newer) compressor may have status lights was productive.   I added info to the question.

Comment: @EdBeal and at-JACK I wish either of you was right.  I so do.  :(. But the code says "locked rotor".

Comment: Well, hopefully the tech can resolve the issue quickly! It's starting to warm up outside; at least in Central NY anyways.

Comment: Locked rotor will go back to an overload condition much like a loose connection or bad starting cap can be the cause. I would not expect a bad cap or contactor at 2 years old but would expect a loose connection especially at the disconnect I have found this more than a few times, loose connection results in low voltage low voltage requires higher current to start so it may look like a locked rotor, I would pull the disconnect verify connections then Meg the motor to ground on both legs, if all the moisture was not removed the oil could have gone acidic and eaten the varnish off the motor wires

Comment: + for adding the info to your question, few do, I saw the comment flagged with my name.  A fan motor is a very small motor and may start fine with a low voltage. You don’t list the brand and model but don’t try to convince the tech on what you think it is. Diagnostics only point to a possibility, megging the motor was the last part I did not explain a high voltage ohm meter is used to test the windings to ground. I would use at least 500v but probably 1000v to verify motor integrity a vfd may detect a ground fault but we don’t know the model. Loose connections or fried windings would be my cks

Comment: Does your multimeter have a capacitance function on it?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel no.   I'm always amenable to buying more toys.  But this is one of those situations where 1) the most likely faults are ones I'm not capable of fixing (I can swap a blown capacitor but I can't fix seized motor bearings or do anything with the liquid/gas system) and 2) my using this as a learning experience comes at the expense of my family's comfort.  It could take me days or weeks.  It's getting hot.  The system is under warranty.   So I put in a call.

Comment: After the issue is resolved you should write your own answer below so that future Googler's can stumble upon this problem and solution :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technicians found low refrigerant and a slow leak at the fill valve.  They replaced the valve, refilled and tested the system and all seems well.

This leaves annoying open questions that can no longer be answered including:

- Why did the [self-diagnostic](https://climate.emerson.com/documents/comfort-alert-troubleshooting-guide-en-2884896.pdf)
  detect *Locked Rotor (4)* and not *Low Charge (1)*?
- How did a "slow leak" spontaneously develop after the end of last summer that progressed as far as immediate low-pressure-shutdown for the beginning of this summer?

The technicians were not interested in contemplating these things so I'll just have to move on without answers but with a working system.

Comment: _Don't forget to give yourself a check mark_

Comment: Nice, glad things are working! As for "Why code 4 and not 1?" It's anybody's guess but one theory is that low refrigerant (1) caused a downstream issue (4) which gets detected first by the system. Either that or the low refrigerant detection system is not working right so you'd have to replace some sensor. If you read the circuit board schematic then it might give you some clues. If you call the manufacturer then they might provide some insight into the board's logic but they are more likely to avoid talking to you and will tell you to speak with a licensed professional.

Comment: As for "How did a "slow leak" spontaneously develop in the fill valve?" Well, HVAC systems are subject to thousands if not millions of micro-vibrations during a heating/cooling season. Don't forget about expansion/contraction and accidental bumps. Things get loose and I'm not sure how much spare money you have lying around to research whether this happened to you :-)